# Check if form submitted and Change javascript variable with if statement

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code to trigger a chain select element. I want to change the cityID to the value of **$(this).val();** if property_city selected if not change it to a value which is pulled from the database. Is this possible?

```
<script>
$( "select[name='property_city']" ).change(function () {

    var cityID = $(this).val();

    if(cityID) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/pages/chain_select/get_postal_town.php",
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {'id':cityID},
            success: function(data) {
                $('select[name="postal_town"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('select[name="postal_town"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'" >'+ value +'</option>');
                });
            }
        });

    }else{
        $('select[name="postal_town"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'" >'+ value +'</option>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to store the previous cityID, and when user will select same id which was pulled from DB you didn't want pull anything from DB.

```
var cities = {};    
$( "select[name='property_city']" ).change(function () {
    if(cities[$(this).val()]) {
       cities[$(this).val()].forEach(function(key, value) {
          $('select[name="postal_town"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'" >'+ value +'</option>');
       });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/pages/chain_select/get_postal_town.php",
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {'id':cityID},
            success: function(data) {
                $('select[name="postal_town"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('select[name="postal_town"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'" >'+ value +'</option>');
                });
                cities[$(this).val()] = data;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: THanks for your efford Nurlan Mirzayev but this code did not work in fact it stopped functioning the chain select.

Comment: I couldn't test it, because I can't call you api. But I tried to explain that you can store your list in some object, and then you can check if city id was selected then give it from object, if not then pull from db.